# Extend INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py from django reusable app

Tags: python, django

I'm building a reusable app that has other django dependencies (`django-rest-framework` for example). I know that if I add it to `install_requires` in `setup.py` it will be packaged. But is there a way I can also extend `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` from the project that is using my packaged app so that it adds all the dependencies? At the moment, with this configuration, if I install my packaged app, I need to add my app name to `INSTALLED_APPS` but also all its dependencies, manually. I would like to think there's a way to avoid having to add all the app's dependencies manually into `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that INSTALLED_APPS is just an array

you can simply import that

```
from othersettings.py import INSTALLED_APPS as IMPORTED_APPS

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
] + IMPORTED_APPS
```

Comment: what happens if the developer already added that app in INSTALLED_APPS? if I add it again, it will be a duplicate and it will fail. I tried to add some logic but the INSTALLED_APPS array is empty when I need it, guess it's initialised after

Comment: If there is such a situation with duplication, you might have to rethink the way you declare these. The app names must be exclusive to those files, If you have trouble use an external py file to hold this array and manage it there. either way it needs to have a standard logic in declaring.