# How to configure django standalone app to install automatically all sub apps?

Tags: python, django, pip

### Problem description

I have django standalone app named `django_codeserver`. It can be loaded from my private package registry as a pip-package.

My app contains about twenty sub-apps for example `django_codeserver.headers`, `django_codeserver.genders` etc.

### Current behaviour

To register all models in my project which uses `django_codeserver`, I have to register all the sub applications in the parent project `INSTALLED_APPS` such as:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
        'django_codeserver.headers',
        'django_codeserver.genders'
        ...
    ]
```

### Preferred behaviour

I would want all the sub apps being registred in the parent project when I only:

1. Install the standalone django app as pip-package (pip install django-codeserver)
2. Register only the parent app in parent project installed apps:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django_codeserver
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching this problem, I couldn't find the exact solution. However we can kind of deal with this problem as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943805/extend-installed-apps-in-settings-py-from-django-reusable-app).

So we are not able to automatically install sub apps, but instead we can reuse application with all sub apps included without directly write all apps in the parent project INSTALLED_APPS.

In that way reusable app installation documentation not changing after adding a new sub app. Also the maintenance of included sub apps is moved from reusable app consumer to its provider.